# Можно изменить md5() на password_hash()?

Tags: php, md5, password-hash

Можно изменить `md5()` на `password_hash()`? Помогите мне, пожалуйста!
Структура MySql написано pasword `VARCHAR(32)` Какое значение надо поставить pasword `VARCHAR(?)` если `password_hash()`?

---

```
<?php
function register_user($register_data) {
    ...

    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    ...
}

function login($phone, $password) {
    ...

    $password = md5($password);

    ...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Документация на password_hash() советует использовать поле в 255 символов.

Comment: Да, думаю хватит с запасом и надолго :-)

Comment: Если вы будете писать более понятно для остальных - вам даже могут попробовать помочь.